# Reference module when overloading a global function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) (specifically, `moment-timezone`) which has an interface called `Duration`.  `Duration.prototype.valueOf()` returns a number, so in JavaScript, calling

```js
setInterval(myCallback, moment.duration(30, 'seconds'));
```

works just fine.

I want to write a TypeScript declaration file that allows this.

#### global.d.ts

```ts
export {};

declare global {
    function setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: Duration, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timeout;

    function setInterval(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: Duration, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timeout;
}
```

When I prepend

```ts
import { Duration } from 'moment-timezone';
```

it treats the .d.ts file as a module declaration, and so it doesn't affect the global namespace.

I thought to move the `import` inside the `declare global` scope, but it still treated `Duration` as `any`.

I've also tried

```ts
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/index.d.ts" />
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've seen a few answers that mentioned something about a setting in tsconfig.json, but that's not an option for me and this really seems like something that should just be possible in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires two steps:

1. Declare the module outside the `declare global` scope.
2. Place `import`s inside the `declare global` scope.

For the OP example:

```ts
export {}

declare module 'moment-timezone';

declare global {
    import { Duration } from 'moment-timezone';

    function setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: Duration, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timeout;

    function setInterval(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: Duration, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timeout;
}
```

---

If you want to import your own types into an external module, place the `import` inside the `declare module` scope, and make sure your types are within a `declare module` scope of their own.

**typings/my-custom-types.d.ts**

```ts
declare module 'my-custom-types' { // <-- this was the missing line that was giving me trouble
    export interface MyStringInterface {
        valueOf(): string;
    }
}
```

**typings/some-lib/index.d.ts**

```ts
declare module 'some-lib' {
    import { MyStringInterface } from 'my-custom-types';

    export interface SomeExistingClass {
        // Add your own signatures
        someExistingMethod(stringParam: MyStringInterface): any;
    }
}
```